# laravel- how to set id by auto increment based on condition?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two registration forms in Laravel using the same register controller. If a user registers as a customer, their id should be 1913xxxxxx where x is the value starting from 1. So it goes like 1913000001,1913000002,..... Similarly, if a user registers as a dealer, their id should be 1911xxxxxxx with an increment from 1 as well. They are both pumping data into the `users` table so I am not sure how do I set the constraint on such a case.

RegisterController.php:

```
/**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Models\Users\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        $user = User::create([
            // Users table
            'user_id'=>$data['1913xxxxxx' or '1911xxxxxx'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
        ]);

        $user->userInfo()->create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'NRIC' => $data['nric'], // Create NRIC field.
        ]);

        $user->userAddresses()->create([
            'address_1' => $data['homeaddress1'],
            'address_2' => $data['homeaddress2'],
            'address_3' => $data['homeaddress3'],
            'zipcode' => $data['postcode'],

            'shipping_address' => $data['shippingaddress']
        ]);

        $user->userContacts()->create([

            'mobile_num' => $data['number'],
            'emergency_num' => $data['emergency']

        ]);

        // check if dealer form is registered, assign dealer role or otherwise

        if ($data['isDealerForm'] == 1) {

            $user->assignRole('2');
        } else {
            $user->assignRole('1');
        }
        // $user->assignRole('1');
        return $user;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You may use `INSERT INTO SELECT` with subquery, e.g. `SELECT MAX(id) + 1 FROM table WHERE id BETWEEN 1911000000 AND 1913000000`. However, your database logic is quite broken and you should think about the extra column "role" instead of playing with ID values.

Comment: Why is it broken?

Comment: @user1597430 is right. you should rather have another column that says `user_type`

Comment: you mean like what @umefarooq suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create another column track_id in your User Table where you will save 1913xxxxxx or 1911xxxxxx for customer or dealer and keep id as primary key auto incriminated. First create user and than save track_id with id like this

```
    $user = User::create([
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => Hash::make($data['password'])
            ]);

   if ($data['isDealerForm'] == 1) {
            $user->track_id = 191300000+$user->id;
            $user->save();
            $user->assignRole('2');
        } else {
            $user->track_id = 191100000+$user->id;
            $user->save();
            $user->assignRole('1');
        }
```

i hope this will solve your problem.

**update**

create your migration like this

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('track_id')->nullable();
```

when you are trying to create user it is looking for track_id value which is not there, with above migration if value is not there than it will be null but later you can update value after creating user.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, what data type should track_id be?

Comment: @LordJesus unsignedBigInteger maybe

Comment: Is it possible to do it like this:  customer register: 191300001, 1913000002 and then dealer registers it should be 1911000001, not 1911000003?